# Transfered Magento website to a VPS and now I have an error

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, server-setup

Unsure how I can remedy this situation. Could this be because I need to update the PHP? Here is the error report I am getting. By the way, how would I read this report so I understand what its asking me to change/fix?

Report:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:78:"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded";i:1;s:2522:"#0 /home/rstern123/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(165): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#6 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#7 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#8 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#9 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#10 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#11 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#12 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#13 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#14 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#15 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#16 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/rstern123/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: have u configure the VPS from scratch or it has a control panel like plesk?

Comment: Server has cpanel

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have **PDO_MySQL** extension loaded. You can check your PHP version if you type `php -v` in console. To list all loaded module type `php -m`. You can also look for specific module like this: `php -m | grep pdo`

See here: [System Requirements for Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.1 and Community Edition 1.9.1](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) and here: [System Requirements Prior to EE 1.14.1 and CE 1.9.1](http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements) for complete list of requirements and supported technologies.